# How can i created a partition for a gust user

Tags: hard-drive

I have a laptop which my brother wants to use sometimes.

I have a password on my user account and important school/work documents that I don't want him touching, and I don't want him installing any unsavory software. I've created a user so he has an account, but I don't want to give him any access to my hard drive.

Can I create a partition (say 30GB off the 750GB hard drive) and restrict his account to only use that partition, without impacting his ability to use the computer(I USE WINDOWS 10)

Comment: If you have an external harddisk, you may want to consider creating a Windows-To-Go installation. He will have his own windows environment and as a rule, Windows-To-Go installations will not allow access to the harddisk. He can even use that harddisk and connect it to another pc and boot there.

Comment: You may find keeping an up-to-date backup will be better insurance (for many possibilities) than second drives / accounts / vm package etc etc

Comment: @SolarMike what about preventing snooping around? Really, a backup is not the solution to this question.

Comment: @LPChip if as you say "snooping" is that much of an issue, then a cheap second hand machine is by far and away the best solution....

Comment: Actually buying a second hdd could be a good alternative.  Then just swap them, he can't touch your stuff, and you can't touch his.

Comment: @cybernard that's exactly why I suggested using an external harddrive and installing a Windows To-Go. That way one gets the full power of a machine without access to the harddrive itself. A much better option than your answer for that very reason.

Answer (score 0):

Another good choice is to use VirtualBox inside a limited user account.
Then he has very limited access to the host, but unlimited access to do anything inside the virtual machine.

FYI:  The only limitation here is the virtual GPU won't be good enough for gaming.  Most other programs should offer a similar experience.

Answer (score 0):

It will be very tricky to do this.

First of all, he must be a standard user, not an administrative user, but that is the easy part.

Secondly, on the C drive, you must revoke as much rights as you can. He will obviously not have access to your C:\Users\* folders, so that includes your My Documents folder. But if you have any other folder created yourself, you need to limit his access manually to those folders as well.

You can't deny access to the Program Files or Windows folders, nor the Users folder, but that last folder is properly limited by default anyway. He still can't write to those folders but he can see the content.

For that reason it is probably a much better option to get him a cheap external harddrive, and then use Windows To-Go to set him up with access to your computer that way.

All he then needs to do is plugin the drive, then boot the computer off of the drive and he will have his own windows environment with all the rights in the world he needs or wants. He won't have access to your harddisk at all, only his own space on the external harddisk. On the plus side, he can bring that harddisk to any Windows 10 machine and use that pc as if it were his own.

To use Windows To-Go, go to your Control Panel and double click Windows To-Go and follow the wizard. NB: I'm not talking about the Settings panel. Control Panel can be accessed by first starting an explorer window, and then typing Control Panel in the titlebar (Since the latest upgrade, direct access to the Control Panel has been removed). Alternatively, search for Windows To-Go in the start menu to directly open the Control Panel Windows To-Go applet.